# How to establish connection between AWS account to outside services or application (which are not on AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, stack, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, jsontemplate

can we able to establish the connection between aws account and other services out side the aws?
the scenario is like: I want to use my stack template from other application for eg some website A  which run the script and create VPC in AWS. for that I need a connection between these two.

is there any way possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What are you wanting to connect?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. my question is, I have AWs account with account ID. Also I have created the stack template to create resources in the aws like VPC, subnet etc. but storing this template on AWS, I want to store it in my website for eg website A. and when I run that template from website A it should create my VPC. so for that I need a connection between my website A to AWS account. how can I able to create that connection. is there any API or command in AWS?

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to trigger the creation of an AWS CloudFormation stack from your own program?

Comment: @Roshani, I do not think so that is possible. You can store the template in your website but you have to execute the template either of following ways. 1. AWS console 2. AWS CLI 3. AWS SDK

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using VPC peering.
Refer to the link below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html

Also you can create a cloud formation template for the existing website in AWS account A and then share that template with other AWS account B.

Comment: VPC peering is for connecting one aws account resource to another aws account. but my website is on my domain and I want the connection from my website to aws account?

Comment: In that case you can use the AWS SDK CLI and connect to another AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

All AWS operations can be controlled via an API call.

You can do it using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), or you can do it via [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) in many programming languages.

If you wish to create an AWS CloudFormation stack, you would use the [CreateStack - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html) API call.